# How do I get this icon to render?

Tags: html

I have a mockup that looks like this:

[image]

It has an icon (the i with the circle around it). How do I get something like that to render?

Comment: What type is is .. SVG?

Comment: You can have a look at [google material icons](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use an icon/image, you could simply use the appropriate HTML character:

```
&#9432;
```

Result: ⓘ

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Google Material Icons font for this.

This snippet will show an example:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="material-icons">info_outline</i>
```

You will have to insert the `<link>` tag before the `</head>` in your html, and the `<i>` tag at the right place in the HTML code.